# Regex capture everything between two tags across multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex in Ruby: http://rubular.com/r/eu9LOQxfTj

```
/<sometag>(.*?)<\/sometag>/im
```

And it successfully matches input like this:

```
<sometag>
  123
  456
</sometag>
```

Which would return

```
123
456
```

However, when I try this in javascript (testing in chrome), it doesn't match anything.
Does javascript's multiline flag mean something else?

I want to capture everything non-greedily between two given tags.
How can I accomplish this in javascript using regex? Here is a [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aL3bsTjI2E01S44F)

```
<sometag>(.*?)<\/sometag>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This is not XML parsing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Javascript does not support multiline expressions when using `.` alone. You have to use `[\s\S]` in place of `.` so an example that satisfies what you want would be:

```
var x = "<sometag>\n\
  123\n\
  456\n\
</sometag>";

var ans = x.match(/<sometag>([\s\S]*?)<\/sometag>/im).pop();

// ans equals " 123  456"
```

note that you still need the `m` modifier.

Comment: You should explain that JS doesn't have support for the `.` to span across multiple lines due to not having the dotall modifier.

Comment: @hwnd good point, added the description. You should edit correct answers to improve them as opposed to just downvoting them as well.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, just simply left the comment.

Comment: 6 years later and `([\s\S]*?)` is still the best solution I found.  in VSCode I've had to add the `\n` to make it `([\s\S\n]*?)`

Comment: Very good answer worked first hand for me with the 'm' modifier